# How to add check constraint validator in serializer in django rest framework?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, check-constraints

I have a model defined as follows :

```
class Order(models.Model):
    
    qty = models.FloatField() 
    pending_qty = models.FloatField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(check=models.Q(
                pending_qty__gte=0), name='pending_qty__gte_0')
        ]
```

The serializer for this models is as follows:

```
class NewOrderSz(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
```

I want to add a validator in the serializer to validate for the 'pending_qty__gte_0' CheckConstraint in the model. How can I do that ?

View for creating an entity is :

```
class NewOrder(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.Order.objects.none()
    serializer_class = serializers.NewOrderSz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define your `pending_qty` with `FloatField` with a `min_value` constraint
and you should be fine

```
class NewOrderSz(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pending_qty = serializers.FloatField(min_value=0)
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Is this inclusive of 0 ?
Also does this add SQL constraints ?

Comment: Yes, it is inclusive, and it doesn't add SQL constraint

Answer (score 1):

```py
class NewOrderSz(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate_pending_qty(self, value):
        if value < 0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Pending Qty Less Than Zero!")
        return value
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation

Comment: Isn't there any in-built validator for CheckConstraints ?

Comment: I not sure, because i never used.